# Expresión regular validacion usuario

Tags: java, regex, java-7

Tengo el siguiente problema: tengo que validar nombres de usuarios con las siguientes condiciones:

- Los nombres de usuario tienen 7 caracteres.
- El primer carácter es una letra.
- Los caracteres 2 y 3 pueden ser letras o números.
- Los 4 últimos son números.
- Desde el primer carácter que sea número, los siguientes deben ser números (ejemplo: `A123456` OK, `A1B3456` NOT OK)

Actualmente tengo esta expresión:

```
(^[A-Za-z]{1,3}([0-9]{4})){1}
```

Pero, por ejemplo `a1234` me lo toma válido. Otra opción sería:

```
(^[A-Za-z]{1,3})[0-9]{0,2}([0-9]{4}){1}
```

Pero el mismo ejemplo me lo toma correcto, solo que se le agrega la posibilidad de que existan 2 números después de hasta 3 letras y luego, sí o sí, 4 números, o sea, está mal.

Si alguien con más experiencia que yo en `regex` me puede ayudar se los agradecería.

Estoy desarrollando en JAVA 7.

Comment: Bienvenido nahuel, te saludo y te doy la bienvenida al sitio!, te invito a realizar el [tour] para 
conocer el funcionamiento básico del sitio y obtener tu primera 
[medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Con respecto a la realización de preguntas que estas sean bien recibidas por la comunidad y obtengas excelentes respuestas, **es muy importante leer [ask]**, saludos!

Answer (score 4):

La expresión que estas buscando si he entendido bien es esta:

```
^[A-Za-z]{1}([A-Za-z]{2}|[0-9]{2}|[A-Za-z][0-9])([0-9]{4}){1}
```

Lo he probado en [esta web de regex online](https://regex101.com/) y me funciona.

Como indicas que el primer valor tiene que ser un caracter usamos:

```
[A-Za-z]{1}
```

comentas que el segundo grupo de tamaño 2 puede ser a1 o aa o 12 por lo que usamos esto:

```
 ([A-Za-z]{2}|[0-9]{2}|[A-Za-z][0-9])
```

Con esto contemplamos las 3 opciones que comentaste.

Espero que te sirva.

Saludos.

Comment: Muchas gracias IDanny7 funciona perfectamente a lo pedido y me lo has explicado de maravilla saludos!!!!

Comment: @nahuel recuerda marcar una respuesta como aceptada si te sirvió. Un saludo

Answer (score 4):

Con Java, tu expresión regular puede ser similar a la siguiente:

```
\A[A-Za-z](?:[A-Za-z]{2}|[A-Za-z][0-9]|[0-9]{2})[0-9]{4}\z
```

Donde:

[image: visual]

```
NODO             EXPLICACIÓN
--------------------------------------------------------------------
  \A               El principio de la cadena
  [A-Za-z]         Uno de: 'A' a 'Z', 'a' a 'z'
  (?:              Agrupar, pero no capturar:
    [A-Za-z]{2}      Uno de: 'A' a 'Z', 'a' a 'z' (2 veces)
   |                O
    [A-Za-z]         Uno de: 'A' a 'Z', 'a' a 'z'
    [0-9]            Uno de: '0' a '9'
   |                O
    [0-9]{2}         Uno de: '0' a '9' (2 veces)
  )                Fin de la agrupación
  [0-9]{4}         Uno de: '0' a '9' (4 veces)
  \z               El final de la cadena
```

Ejemplo de uso:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String input;

    input = "A123456";
    System.out.println(
            input.matches("\\A[A-Za-z](?:[A-Za-z]{2}|[A-Za-z][0-9]|[0-9]{2})[0-9]{4}\\z")
    ); // imprime "true"

    input = "A1B3456";
    System.out.println(
            input.matches("\\A[A-Za-z](?:[A-Za-z]{2}|[A-Za-z][0-9]|[0-9]{2})[0-9]{4}\\z")
    ); // imprime "false"

    input = "a1234";
    System.out.println(
            input.matches("\\A[A-Za-z](?:[A-Za-z]{2}|[A-Za-z][0-9]|[0-9]{2})[0-9]{4}\\z")
    ); // imprime "false"
}
```